# Renaming MultiIndex columns is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename, multi-index

I am trying to rename the columns of my data frame on the fly. The reason is I want to do something like

```
df.rename(..).plot()
```

This is how I attempt to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

cols = [(100,i) for i in range(1, 6)]
cols_replace = ['Sensor ' + str(i) for i in range(1, len(cols)+1)]

rename_dict = dict(zip(df.columns, cols_replace))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, len(cols)), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols))

print(df.rename(columns=rename_dict))
```

However, for some reason this does not work as the resulting data frame still does not show the column names that I am seeking:

```
        100                                        
          1         2         3         4         5
0  0.374540  0.950714  0.731994  0.598658  0.156019
1  0.155995  0.058084  0.866176  0.601115  0.708073
2  0.020584  0.969910  0.832443  0.212339  0.181825
3  0.183405  0.304242  0.524756  0.431945  0.291229
4  0.611853  0.139494  0.292145  0.366362  0.456070
```

Why is this not working as I'd expect and is there a way how I can achieve this?

---

The content of `rename_dict` is:

```
{(100, 1): 'Sensor 1', 
 (100, 2): 'Sensor 2', 
 (100, 3): 'Sensor 3', 
 (100, 4): 'Sensor 4', 
 (100, 5): 'Sensor 5'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `rename` with a `level` argument -

```
df = df.rename(columns='Sensor {}'.format , level=1)
```

Thanks to Zero for the shorthand improvement. Alternatively,

```
i = df.columns.levels[1]   # OP's suggestion, for more flexibility!
j = ['Sensor ' + str(x) for x in range(1, len(cols) + 1)]
rename_dict = dict(zip(i, j))

df = df.rename(columns=rename_dict, level=1)
```

```
df
        100                                        
   Sensor 1  Sensor 2  Sensor 3  Sensor 4  Sensor 5
0  0.374540  0.950714  0.731994  0.598658  0.156019
1  0.155995  0.058084  0.866176  0.601115  0.708073
2  0.020584  0.969910  0.832443  0.212339  0.181825
3  0.183405  0.304242  0.524756  0.431945  0.291229
4  0.611853  0.139494  0.292145  0.366362  0.456070
```

Since you want to apply the renaming operation on the *first* level (rather than the zeroth), pass `level=1`.

Comment: If you change = `i = range(1, 6)` to `i = df.columns.levels[1]` it's more flexible and exactly what I was looking for. I thought I can provide keys as tuples as long as they are contained in the index - apparently that is not the case. Thanks, as always :) The reason is because ofc the values must not necessarily be just `range(..)` but could be arbitrary.

Comment: @displayname No worries. Also, nice tune-up, thanks.

Comment: Shorthand with `df.rename(columns='Sensor {}'.format , level=1)`